# Fencepost issue: I need a recursive function that skips executing a section when it is first called

Tags: html, c++, css, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to make a C++ program that creates a formatted CSS file.

What I first do is take the HTML file and build it into a tree with nodes of the following type.

```
struct node
{
    std::string element_type;
    std::vector<std::string> class_list;
    std::string iden;
    std::vector<node*> children;
};
```

Right now I'm trying to make a function that takes the root of the tree and returns a string that is the formatted CSS of the document (with the only attributes it's looking at being CSS `class`es and `id`s).

For example, if the HTML file is

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div class="row">
             <h1 id="title">Here's my title</h1>    
         </div>
         <div class="row red">
             <p>Here's some text inside a div of class row and red</p>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <a href="google.com">Cool, you can click here to go to Google</a>
         </row>
    </body>
</html>
```

then, after that had been made into a tree, I have a function

```
std::string DocTree::_tree2Str(node * rt)
```

which I intend to have return the string

```
html {}
  html > body {}
     html > body > div.row {}   
       html > body > div.row > h1#title {}
       html > body > div.row > a {} 
     html > body > div.row.red {}  
       html > body > div.row.red > p {}
```

Here's my implementation of the function:

```
std::string DocTree::_tree2Str(node * rt)
{
    std::string css("");
    if (rt)
    {
        css.append(rt->element_type);

        if (!rt->class_list.empty())
        {
            for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it(rt->class_list.begin()), offend(rt->class_list.end()); it != offend; ++it)
            {
                css.append("." + *it);
            }
        }
        if (!rt->iden.empty())
        {
            css.append("#" + rt->iden);
        }
        if (!rt->children.empty())
        {
            for (std::vector<node*>::iterator it(rt->children.begin()), offend(rt->children.end()); it != offend; ++it)
            {
                css.append("\n\t" + _tree2Str(*it));
            }
        }
    }
    return css;
}
```

The only thing I've skipped is the `" > "` because I don't how to work that into the recursive function. It should be printed at the beginning of the function every time the function is called **except for the very first time**.

Also, there might be other logical fallacies. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `private _innerTree2Str(node * rt, bool printGt)` method that contains the contents of your `_tree2Str` method, plus the line `if(printGt) css.append(" > ");` at the top.  All calls to `_tree2Str(node)` become calls to `_innerTree2Str(node, true)`

Then `_tree2Str` becomes

```
std::string DocTree::_tree2Str(node * rt)
{
    return _innerTree2Str(rt, false);
}
```

This way the first time you call `_innerTree2Str` the `printGt` variable is false and you won't append `" > "`, every other time `printGt` will be true

Rather than creating a second method you could instead add the `printGt` parameter directly to `_tree2Str`, but then you'll be relying on the caller to remember to pass in a `false` for the `printGt` parameter

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'm guessing this is a well-known procedure for this type of fencepost problem?

Comment: @DonaldKnuthLied Yeah, in some form or another; for example in some languages you could use a closure for the `printGt` variable rather than having to treat it as a parameter.  But the principle is the same - you've got a flag that gets flipped after the first iteration or recursive call.  It's a bit trickier if the fencepost is at the end instead of the beginning - if your functions don't have side-effects then it might be easiest to just backtrack one iteration once you've reached the end, flip the flag, and re-run the final iteration.